# Pass html flash variables to a text box inside a movie clip

Tags: flash

I am trying to pass object variables on an html page into a movie clip that contains a text field. If I put the text field on the root and use this.

```
function loaderComplete(myEvent:Event)
{
   var myQueryStrings=this.loaderInfo.parameters;
   licensetext.text=myQueryStrings.licensetext;
}

this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
```

it works.

But if I put the textfield in a movie clip and use this where the movie clip is called pass

```
function loaderComplete(myEvent:Event) 
{
   var myQueryStrings=this.loaderInfo.parameters;
   this.pass.licensetext.text=myQueryStrings.licensetext;
}
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
```

nothing is loaded. I have clicked on my movie clip and added the action script. I also put the action script inside the movie clip timeline and on the root timeline, but nothing works. I am using Flash CS3 and actionscript 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
this.pass.licensetext.text=myQueryStrings.licensetext;
```

To

```
pass.licensetext.text=myQueryStrings.licensetext;
```

Edit: Make sure you're referencing the instance name of the MovieClip, not the name in the library.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. I tried on the movie timeline, the root timeline and attached to the movie clip.

Comment: If you're passing a variable from the root timeline, you should only pass it from the root timeline. Are you sure the TextField is called 'licensetext' amd the MovieClip is called 'pass'? Do any errors come up?

Comment: @Visualtribe Make sure the TextField is dynamic as well.

Comment: If the text box is on the root timeline it works. If it inside a movie clip it doesn't work. How would I pass the variable into the movie clip. this.pass.licensetext.text doesn't work. I would think it should since I am calling the movie clip.

Comment: @Visualtribe In AS3 it would work exactly how I wrote it in my answer - and exactly how you wrote it in your question. Can I just ask why you're not using AS3?

Comment: And yes they are called those names.

Comment: Ok, I exported it out as AS3 and it worked. I initially got an error that I couldn't export a text variable, so I thought the whole thing wouldn't work, but it does now thanks.

Comment: @Visualtribe Unless you have a specific (and VERY good) reason to use AS2 - please use AS3. It is the current technology and really is all that should be used now in terms of flash development. Remember that Adobe released AS3 in 2006. According to [this](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/actionscript3_overview.html) article by Adobe, AS3 runs 10 times faster than its predecessor (note that this was written on the original release of AS3 and the improvements will have improved much more since). Please mark my answer as correct if you're happy with it, otherwise let me know.

Comment: I have one more question, I set the text box to multiline and I had a <br/> before with AS2 and it returned a line. Now it just shows the <br/>

Comment: Instead of .text try using .htmlText and it should work.